# Error found in console for indexedDB. Assistance needed

Tags: javascript, html, database, indexing, indexeddb

I'm getting an error for the indexedDB I'm trying to make. "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'index' on 'IDBObjectStore': The specified index was not found." It says it's not found but I believe I correctly created the index a couple lines before.

p.s. - I'm learning as a I go so bare with me I'm not as knowledgeable about indexedDB

The code is below

```
//Credit @alexeagleson - github

// This works on all devices/browsers, and uses IndexedDBShim as a final fallback
const indexedDB =
  window.indexedDB ||
  window.mozIndexedDB ||
  window.webkitIndexedDB ||
  window.msIndexedDB ||
  window.shimIndexedDB;

//window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase("MeteorDynamicImportCache");//
//window.location.reload();//

// Open (or create) the database
const request = indexedDB.open("Workouts", 1);

request.onerror = function (event) {
  console.error("An error occurred with IndexedDB");
  console.error(event);
};

// Create the schema on create and version upgrade
request.onupgradeneeded = function () {
  const db = request.result;
  const store = db.createObjectStore("workouts", { keyPath: "id" });
  store.createIndex("name_Type", ["Type"], { unique: false });
  store.createIndex("specifics", ["Type","Where","For"], {unique: false,});
};

request.onsuccess = function () {
  console.log("Database opened successfully");

  const db = request.result;
  const transaction = db.transaction("workouts", "readwrite");

  const store = transaction.objectStore("workouts");
  const nameIndex = store.index("name_Type"); [tag:ERROR HERE]
  const specificsIndex = store.index("specifics");
```

I tried alterning the letter case because that seemed to clear up the last similar error i got. I'm not really sure what else to do.

Comment: I didnt even notice that, but after changing it its still throwing the same error.

Comment: You probably created the database, then implemented or changed the onupgradeneeded handler, then did not update the database version to trigger the onupgradeneeded handler.